# Buffer deduplication procedure will be skipped when flatbuffer library is not properly loaded. (Tensorflow Lite)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, flatbuffers

Every time I convert a model to a `tflite` format, I always receive this WARNING. I wonder if this library will further reduce the model size. If so, I hope to use it. But I can't find relevant information in Google, and `flatbuffer`'s documentation doesn't seem to mention how to simply install it so that tensorflow can invoke it.